# How to use Case Select in GOOGLE SHEET

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, case

I'm trying to enter the formula in cell A4 in sheet1 depending on value at cell AA1 but not working and help me if cell AA1 is blank or N/A or NEW then do notthing.

```
function setFormulaspercase(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()          
   var cellcase = ("AA1");
   var formulaCell = ("A4");

    if (cellcase == 'A') {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(formulaCell).setFormula("=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,SELECT B,G,C,H,L,O,J,D,S,T)");

    if (cellcase == 'B') {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(formulaCell).setFormula("=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,SELECT B,C,G,H,L,O,J,D,S,T)");
  
    if (cellcase == 'C') {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(formulaCell).setFormula("=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,SELECT B,C,G,L,H,O,J,D,S,T)");
```

Modified from Tanaike scripts

```
function setFormulaspercase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var cellcase = sh2.getRange("G1").getValue();
  var formulaCell = "A4";
  var range = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange(formulaCell);
  if (cellcase == 'A') {
    range.setFormula('=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,"SELECT B,G,C,H,L,O,J,D,S,T")');
  } else if (cellcase == 'B') {
    range.setFormula('=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,"SELECT B,C,G,H,L,O,J,D,S,T")');
  } else if (cellcase == 'C') {
    range.setFormula('=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,"SELECT B,C,G,L,H,O,J,D,S,T")');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the formula to the cell "A4" on "sheet1" by checking the value of cell "AA1" on the active sheet.

#### Modification points:

- `var cellcase = ("AA1")` is the a1Notation. This is not the value of the cell "AA1".
- In your situation, the if statement is required to be modified.
- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(formulaCell)` might not be "sheet1". In this case, `getSheetByName` can be used. And, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(formulaCell)` can be declared at outside of the if statement.
- In your script, it is required to modify the formula. Please enclise the query with the double quotes.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function setFormulaspercase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cellcase = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("AA1").getValue();
  var formulaCell = "A4";
  var range = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange(formulaCell);
  if (cellcase == 'A') {
    range.setFormula('=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,"SELECT B,G,C,H,L,O,J,D,S,T")');
  } else if (cellcase == 'B') {
    range.setFormula('=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,"SELECT B,C,G,H,L,O,J,D,S,T")');
  } else if (cellcase == 'C') {
    range.setFormula('=QUERY(\'Sheet2\'!B4:U,"SELECT B,C,G,L,H,O,J,D,S,T")');
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: @tt3 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: How to modify the script to get the value of cellcase is from cell "G1" of SHEET2?

Comment: @tt3 About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, about your new question, I cannot understand what you want to do. In order to correctly understand about your new question, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I modified this line =>  var cellcase = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("AA1").getValue();    to these 2 line =>  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var cellcase = sh2.getRange("G1").getValue();